# What was Steve talking about when he asked Sharon whether Peggy knew?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, Sharon and Steve walk back to a hotel after the funeral and before Sam Wilson rushes to tell him about the terrorist attack, Steve asks Sharon if Peggy knew. What was the secret he was asking she knew?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yep, another user and I covered that under your answer, I just forgot to delete this comment, Mb

Answer (score 9):

Just before he asks if Peggy knew, he says what he’s asking about:

> STEVE: I've been meaning to ask you. When you were spying on me from across the hall...
>
> SHARON: You mean when I was doing my job.
>
> STEVE: Did Peggy know?
>
> https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=captain-america-civil-war

So, he’s asking whether Peggy knew that her niece, Sharon, was spying on her ex-colleague and love interest, Steve. (Sharon spied on Steve in *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*.)

Comment: This seems correct when you ignore the next line. But once you take into account the next line it doesn't really make sense anymore. `She kept so many secrets. I didn't want her to have one from you.` So that leads me to believe that Steve had done something that Sharon had witnessed, and Steve wanted to know if Sharon told her. Although I could be totally misunderstanding that. (I bring this up, because that's what stopped me from answering with the exact same quote.)

Comment: @Edlothiad In bare text, that line is rather clunky - but in the context, Sharon is saying that she didn't want Peggy to be keeping a secret (about Sharon being a SHIELD operative and monitoring Steve) away from Steve, rather than Sharon revealing a secret about Steve to Peggy

Comment: @HorusKol Ah I see, she hadn't told Peggy, as otherwise Peggy would be keeping a secret from Steve.

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the [junior novelisation](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Marvels-Captain-America-Civil-Junior/dp/031627142X). Steve was asking whether Peggy Carter knew that her Sharon's assignment was to spy on Steve. Apparently she did not, but note that she *was* aware that her niece was a S.H.I.E.L.D. agent.

> Before she went into her room and he lost his nerve, Steve had one more thing he needed to know. “I’ve been meaning to ask you. When you were spying on me from across the hall…”
>   “You mean when I was doing my job?” she said, gently correcting him.
>   Fair enough, Steve thought. “Did Peggy know?”
>   **“She kept so many secrets. I didn’t want her to have one from you.” It was a hard thing for Steve to hear, but he understood.** “Thanks for walking me back.”